# Connect with Microsoft Graph using ADFS On-premise Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, adfs

I have a Web Application which uses auth with ADFS On-premise. Now, I would like to use Microsoft Graph in this Web Application for receiving mails, for example. I need a token for connecting with Microsoft Graph, but ADFS token I have isn't valid. I guess I need a new token for Graph, but I want use credentials obtained with ADFS auth.

Is possible to connect with Graph? If so, How?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph API will not accept a token from your ADFS.
It will only accept one from Azure AD.
The Web app should be modified to authenticate the user with Azure AD; the access token can then be acquired.

If your users are synced to Azure AD, they can authenticate with the same accounts as before.